# I am trying to get the matched elements from an array by using strings MNPPORTIN,00:11:16 with regular exp & grep function

Tags: perl

I am trying to get the matched elements from an array by using strings MNPPORTIN,00:11:16 with regular exp & grep function, but i am getting all the elements from the elements. I am looking for the whole elemnts from the array that matched with the provided string.

```perl
$a[0]="00\:11\:16 01\-03\-2019\: Watching process \"clear_dialtunes_errors.sh -daemon\"\, minimum instances\: 1\, maximum instances\: 1 \(Queue\: SV_MO\)";
$a[1]="00\:11\:16 01\-03\-2019\: Watching process \"DN\=MNPPORTIN_1\"\, minimum instances\: 1\, maximum instances: 1 \(Queue\: SV_HI\,ACRM\,F2\)";
$a[2]="00\:11\:16 01\-03\-2019\: Watching process \"DN\=MNPPORTIN_WSALE_1\"\, minimum instances\: 1\, maximum instances\: 1 \(Queue\: SV_HI\,ACRM\,F2)";
$a[3]="08\:51\:41 01\-03\-2019\: FS\: \/platform\/SUNW\,Sun\-Blade\-T6320\/lib\/sparcv9\/libc_psr\/libc_psr_hwcap2\.so\.1 1918198 inodes";
$a[4]="08\:51\:41 01\-03\-2019\: FS\: \/dev\/md\/dsk\/d5 29989287 inodes";
$a[5]="08\:51\:41 01\-03\-2019\: FS\: \/opt\/apps01\/opt\/oracle 29989287 inodes";
@j=join("\n",@a);
print("The value for \@j is :\n@j \n");
#@st=split("\n",$j);
#print("The value for \@st is : @st \n");
@b=(@a=~m/00\:11\:16/);
print("The value for \$b is : $b \n");
@c=grep(/MNPPORTIN/,@j);
print("The value for \@c is :\n@c \n");
$s=@a;
for($i=0;$i<$s;$i++)
{
    if($j[$i]=~m/MNPPORTIN/)
    {
        print "Match found \n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "No match found for   $a[$i] \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: [join](http://p3rl.org/join) returns a string, not an array. Also, turn on [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings): `Applying pattern match (m//) to @arr will act on scalar(@arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an attempt to answer, just trying to understand what you want to achieve. Maybe the following is the code you wanted to write?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @a = (
    q{00:11:16 01-03-2019: Watching process "clear_dialtunes_errors.sh -daemon", minimum instances: 1, maximum instances: 1 (Queue: SV_MO)},
    q{00:11:16 01-03-2019: Watching process "DN=MNPPORTIN_1", minimum instances: 1, maximum instances: 1 (Queue: SV_HI,ACRM,F2)},
    q{00:11:16 01-03-2019: Watching process "DN=MNPPORTIN_WSALE_1", minimum instances: 1, maximum instances: 1 (Queue: SV_HI,ACRM,F2)},
    q{08:51:41 01-03-2019: FS: /platform/SUNW,Sun-Blade-T6320/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr/libc_psr_hwcap2.so.1 1918198 inodes},
    q{08:51:41 01-03-2019: FS: /dev/md/dsk/d5 29989287 inodes},
    q{08:51:41 01-03-2019: FS: /opt/apps01/opt/oracle 29989287 inodes},
);


my $j = join("\n", @a);
print("The value for \$j is :\n${j}\n\n");

my @b = grep { /00:11:16/ } @a;
print("The value for \@b is :\n@{b}\n\n");

my @c = grep { /MNPPORTIN/ } ($j);
print("The value for \@c is :\n@{c}\n\n");

foreach my $a (@a) {
    if($a =~ /MNPPORTIN/) {
        print "Match found \n";
    } else {
        print "No match found for ${a}\n";
    }
}

exit 0;
```

Output

```
$ perl dummy.pl
The value for $j is :
00:11:16 01-03-2019: Watching process "clear_dialtunes_errors.sh -daemon", minimum instances: 1, maximum instances: 1 (Queue: SV_MO)
00:11:16 01-03-2019: Watching process "DN=MNPPORTIN_1", minimum instances: 1, maximum instances: 1 (Queue: SV_HI,ACRM,F2)
00:11:16 01-03-2019: Watching process "DN=MNPPORTIN_WSALE_1", minimum instances: 1, maximum instances: 1 (Queue: SV_HI,ACRM,F2)
08:51:41 01-03-2019: FS: /platform/SUNW,Sun-Blade-T6320/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr/libc_psr_hwcap2.so.1 1918198 inodes
08:51:41 01-03-2019: FS: /dev/md/dsk/d5 29989287 inodes
08:51:41 01-03-2019: FS: /opt/apps01/opt/oracle 29989287 inodes

The value for @b is :
00:11:16 01-03-2019: Watching process "clear_dialtunes_errors.sh -daemon", minimum instances: 1, maximum instances: 1 (Queue: SV_MO) 00:11:16 01-03-2019: Watching process "DN=MNPPORTIN_1", minimum instances: 1, maximum instances: 1 (Queue: SV_HI,ACRM,F2) 00:11:16 01-03-2019: Watching process "DN=MNPPORTIN_WSALE_1", minimum instances: 1, maximum instances: 1 (Queue: SV_HI,ACRM,F2)

The value for @c is :
00:11:16 01-03-2019: Watching process "clear_dialtunes_errors.sh -daemon", minimum instances: 1, maximum instances: 1 (Queue: SV_MO)
00:11:16 01-03-2019: Watching process "DN=MNPPORTIN_1", minimum instances: 1, maximum instances: 1 (Queue: SV_HI,ACRM,F2)
00:11:16 01-03-2019: Watching process "DN=MNPPORTIN_WSALE_1", minimum instances: 1, maximum instances: 1 (Queue: SV_HI,ACRM,F2)
08:51:41 01-03-2019: FS: /platform/SUNW,Sun-Blade-T6320/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr/libc_psr_hwcap2.so.1 1918198 inodes
08:51:41 01-03-2019: FS: /dev/md/dsk/d5 29989287 inodes
08:51:41 01-03-2019: FS: /opt/apps01/opt/oracle 29989287 inodes

No match found for 00:11:16 01-03-2019: Watching process "clear_dialtunes_errors.sh -daemon", minimum instances: 1, maximum instances: 1 (Queue: SV_MO)
Match found 
Match found 
No match found for 08:51:41 01-03-2019: FS: /platform/SUNW,Sun-Blade-T6320/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr/libc_psr_hwcap2.so.1 1918198 inodes
No match found for 08:51:41 01-03-2019: FS: /dev/md/dsk/d5 29989287 inodes
No match found for 08:51:41 01-03-2019: FS: /opt/apps01/opt/oracle 29989287 inodes
```